# Slicker way to prove $\rho$ is a metric

Tags: metric-spaces, alternative-proof

Let $d$ be a metric on $X$, and define $\rho: X^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $$\rho(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$$
The difficulty is in checking the triangle inequality. So, I can prove this by writing $f(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}$ and showing (by doing some algebra) that
$$ f(A)+f(B)\ge f(A+B)$$
From which it follows that $A+B\ge C \implies f(A)+f(B) \ge f(C)$, and this is enough to verify the triangle inequality.

I have two problems with this: one, it's quite messy, and two, it doesn't really give me any intuition for what the metric $\rho$ looks like. It's obviously bounded, and it sort of squishes the whole space $X$ into a unit disc. Is there a good way of thinking about it?

For instance, the claim $f(A)+f(B) \ge f(A+B)$ looks similar to (but not quite the same as) the definition of concavity, and I could check $f$ is concave by looking at its derivative.

Comment: It feels great to write this, but check out Batman's answer in the link! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686792/showing-rho-x-y-fracdx-y1dx-y-is-a-metric-space

Comment: The mean value theorem! Yeah that fits what I wanted, thank you! I'vew left an upvote on his answer.

Comment: You're welcome. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Note $f:[0,\infty]\to\mathcal{R}$ given by $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is increasing as $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$, Therefore
$$\rho(x,z)=\frac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,z)}\le \frac{d(x,y)+d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)}=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)}+\frac{d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)}$$
$$\rho(x,z)\le \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}+\frac{d(y,z)}{1+d(y,z)}=\rho (x,y)+\rho (y,z)$$